# Conversion of Dataset into DataFrame

Tags: scala, dataframe, dataset

I need help in converting below Dataset code into DataFrame. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Dataset has a method .toDF

Comment: I don't see the relation between the question and the provided code. What is the issue with your code? If `Member.getExtSchema(...)` returns an `ExtMember`, then it should work

Comment: For info, Dataframe is just an untyped Dataset: `type DataFrame = Dataset[Row]`

Answer (score 2):

A `Dataframe` is a `Dataset[Row]`. any schema existing in the Dataset will be kept in the Dataframe.

Regarding the question on conversion, there is a simple way by using the `.toDF()` method :

```
val myDs : Dataset[Member] = someDs
val myDf : Dataframe = myDs.toDF()
```

Now there is a conversion in your method signature (`Member` => `ExtMember`) that seems to require some custom coding